# Open SecureCRT using perl

Tags: perl, automation, ui-automation, secure-crt

I am using secureCRT. I want to automate secureCRT using perl. I intend to open the secureCRT, enter hostname,username and password and then execute a command in secureCRT. Is there any perl object to work with secureCRT.

Is there any command like

Win32::OLE (SecureCRT.Application)

for perl

I am unable to find any perl documentation for using secureCRT

Comment: why do you automate SecureCRT and not simply work with ssh?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to interact with a server that has a ssh daemon running, I suggest you to have a look at [`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl) and skip trying to use `SecureCRT` from Perl.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Besides using some Perl module for SSH (i.e. Net::SSH2 or Net::SSH::Any), there is also [PAC Manager](https://sites.google.com/site/davidtv/), a connection manager similar to SecureCRT but written and scriptable in Perl.